# Pycharm: How to turn highlighted lines of code into a 'def ###():'

Tags: python, function, pycharm

I have several hundred lines of code which I need to change to put into a single `def ####():`. Is there a way to turn them into one `def` without having to go through line and typing space or pressing the tab button?

I know I can click the scroll button on a mouse to select multiple lines at once, but I don't currently have a mouse on me and I'm using the touch pad on my laptop. Is there a way to do it by highlight the lines of code?

I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/extract-method.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyCharm, you can do a block-indent by selecting all the lines of the block at once, and simply indent them all by using `TAB` (unindent by using `Shift + TAB`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use shift and arrow keys to select the code you want and indent it by pressing TAB